# Firefox addon: Page-mod script slow while scratchpad runs just fine

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox-addon

I've been trying to develop a firefox addon that allows you to find artists on cgsociety.com/gallery whose works you've saved, but the script becomes quite laggy. My problem is that this code runs pretty smooth in scratchpad, no major problems, but when I load it into the same webpage using a page-mod, this script becomes essentially unusable, pictures flicker continuously and it's not pleasant to look at. I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong, or will a page-mod not work for this sort of thing? I'm also using cfx, is that a potential source of my problems? Thanks for any and all help!

```
// Scratchpad code
var un$ = jQuery.noConflict()
var testArray = [ // artists to test with
  'Brad',
  'James Paick',
  'Donglu Yu',
  'Martin Deschambault',
  'allenweis',
  'Jason Seiler',
  'Paul Chadeisson',
  'Torren Thomas'
]
var dict = testArray  

function magic() {
  un$('.sizeimage').stop(true, true).animate({
    opacity: 0.25
  }, 250); // set everything dark
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) { // find artworks to highlight
    var name = dict[i];
    var finderthingy = 'a:contains(\'' + name + '\') > div > img';
    var allImg = un$(".sizeimage")
    var selImg = un$(finderthingy)
    selImg.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 350, function () {
      un$(".sizeimage").attr('class', 'wasAltered') // remember what is changed
    });
  }
}
un$(document).ready(magic).scroll(magic); // running it
$ = jQuery.noConflict()
```

Here's where I include the script with the page-mod in the main.js file:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ["http://www.cgsociety.org/gallery","http://www.cgsociety.org/gallery/"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jQ-1.11.3.js"),data.url("artdisplay.js")],
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
  contentScriptWhen: "end"
});
```

Thank you for you time guys!

- Will

Comment: Interesting research/case study